# Nhibernate does not save a collection of strings

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am not new to nhibernate, but I can't get it to save/update a collection of strings.

I have an entity  and this entity has 3 collections of strings (`Iesi.ISet<string>`).

I make changes to the string collections on the entity, and call `Session.Save`, `Session.Update`, `Session.SaveOrUpdate`, nothing works.

This is all in an nhibernate transcation, the transaction is being commited.   I can see it all happening in NHProf, no errors, no exceptions.  Nhibernate simply ignores my collections.

It updates the parent entity fine.

Yes, cascade is set. to save-update, Ive also tried all-delete-orphan, which is actually what i want.

The collections on the entity are a `Iese.Iset<string>`.  They are initialized in the constructor of the entity using new `Iesi.Collections.Generic.HasheSet<string>()`.

I will paste in the mapping file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NameRemovedV2.Web" namespace="NameRemovedV2.Web.Models">
      <class name="NameRemovedUser" table="NameRemovedUsers">
        <id name="NameRemovedUserID">
          <generator class="hilo"></generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one cascade="save-update" class="NameRemovedSite" column="NameRemovedSiteID" name="Site" not-null="true" foreign-key="FK_NameRemovedSites_NameRemovedUsers"></many-to-one>
        <property name="Username" not-null="true" unique="true" unique-key="UX_NameRemovedUsers"></property>
        <property name="FirstName" not-null="false"></property>
        <property name="LastName" not-null="false"></property>
        <property name="EmailAddress" not-null="false"></property>
        <property name="DealerCode" not-null="false"></property>
        <property name="RegistrationDate" not-null="true"></property>
        <set cascade="save-update" inverse="true" name="LeftSide" table="LeftSides">
          <key column="NameRemovedUserID" not-null="true" foreign-key="FK_NameRemovedUsers_LeftSides"></key>
          <element column="ElementID"  not-null="true"></element>
        </set>
        <set cascade="save-update" inverse="true" name="RightSide" table="RightSides">
          <key column="NameRemovedUserID" not-null="true" foreign-key="FK_NameRemovedUsers_RightSides" ></key>
          <element column="ElementID" not-null="true"></element>
        </set>
        <set generic="true" cascade="save-update" inverse="true" name="Hide" table="Hides">
          <key column="NameRemovedUserID" not-null="true" foreign-key="FK_NameRemovedUsers_Hides" ></key>
          <element column="ElementID" type="String" not-null="true"></element>
        </set>
      </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the `inverse="true"` attribute in your set mappings. This informs NHibernate that the other (one) side of the relationship will be examined for changes when the session is flushed. With a set of strings there is no way to associate a string to the parent except by adding it to the collection. Try removing the `inverse="true"` attribute or setting it to false (the default).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it up nicely.   I've always wondered when it would be appropriate to set inverse to false, i've never needed that before.